# How to set ascending or descending order in gujarati website's option tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hello I create a website in Gujarati language. I want display the data of database to show in option menu in order of **Gujarati Vowels and Consonants** .How can I **arrange** it in this order?

I tried ascending and descending order but it is not work in Gujarati language.
Here is Some Part of option tag Which i want to arrange

[image: Gujarati Language Dropdown]

Comment: sorry this is not duplicate question .As you say above that question is for displaying Gujarati language from database where i want to know about arranging that content into ascending or descending order.....

Comment: This post talks about collation too, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: I already fetch the data from database now the main problem is to arrange it.

Comment: Can you please check your current collation? try running `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE NAME LIKE 'my_tablename';` to check you are indeed using `utf8mb4`

Comment: collation is:latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: That is why MySQL get the order wrong then. Try running `ALTER TABLE my_tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` and see if it gets the order right.

Comment: It is Not working.....

Comment: What is the query you are running? Didn't the order change at all?

Comment: the order is changed but it doesn't show in Gujarati Vowels and Consonants order.The query is:select * from my_tablename order by c_name DESC

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to help you more on that since I don't have a dataset to play with, nor am I able to detect the right order by myself. My only guess would be to try to change collation until you get what you need with `SELECT * FROM my_tablename COLLATE ????;` trying different collation. I would be surprised, although it is still a possibility, that MySQL do not handle the collation you are seeking.

Comment: Can you please remove duplicate question mark because it is not repeated question....because i want to arrange it in order.....and ya thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you'll want to use a [`Collator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) from the  [`intl` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php), and I believe the locale will be `gu_IN`.

eg:

```
$c = new Collator('gu_IN');
$c->sort($myArray);
```

In MySQL so long as you're using a UTF8 collation your strings *should* sort correctly, assuming that the UTF8 codepoints for Gujarati are in the correct order.